# Cannot repeat same condition twice on ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have the following code...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <span>
            Comments
        </span>
    </div>

    @*<div class="col-md-7">*@
    <div class="col-md-7" ng-class="{'has-error': TaskObject.Comments.length > 500}">
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="TaskObject.Comments" maxlength="500"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

and somewhere else I use an identical element

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <span>
            Comments
        </span>
    </div>

    @*<div class="col-md-7">*@
    <div class="col-md-7" ng-class="{'has-error': TaskObject.Comments.length > 500}">
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="TaskObject.Comments" maxlength="500"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

the thing is, when I run the site, it throws the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[ng-class='{'has-error': TaskObject.Comments.length
```

However, I noticed that if I delete whichever I like, or event add a ; at the end of ONE of the conditions, the error disappears.

Any ideas on why that happens?

Comment: you broke html with your greaterThan mark. You can try to use `500<x` form.

Comment: Also you can write filter for this. Or own `maxlength` directive.

Answer (score 3):

At initial `TaskObject.Comments` was `null` and `null` doesn't have `length` property.

Add a extra check within `ng-class`

Like this

```
 ng-class="{'has-error': TaskObject.Comments && TaskObject.Comments.length > 500}"
```